# React error when removing input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure if it´s a react issue or not but I am struggling a lot with this issue. I tried to create just a simple example to post out of my project:

https://codepen.io/as3script/pen/VMbNdz?editors=1111

There are four buttons on the example.

To reproduce the problem press each of the first three buttons to create a text input from and enter a value. For example enter 100 into the first one, 200 into the second and 300 into the third. Now press the fourth button to remove the first input.

It should keep the second and third with their respective values, 200 and 300, but instead it´s showing 100 in the second and 200 in the third.

---

This code is the same as it is on CodePen, it just didn't allow the link to be posted without this.

```
class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {filtersArr:[]}
    this.addButtons = this.addButtons.bind(this);
    this.removeButtons = this.removeButtons.bind(this);
    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

   addButtons(e){     
    let tempArr = this.state.filtersArr;

    tempArr.push({comp:this.getInput(e.target.id), id:e.target.id});

    this.setState({filtersArr:tempArr});
  }

  removeButtons(e){
    console.log(e.target.id);
    let newArr = this.state.filtersArr.filter((filter)=>{
      return (filter.id !=='FirstButton')
    })
    this.setState({filtersArr:newArr});
  }

  onChangeHandler(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  getInput(id){
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>{id}</h6>
        <input
          id="min"
          type="text"
          placeholder="min"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    let styles = {
      display:'inline-block'
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Add three buttons and enter the number in each input, and remove amt.</p>
        <button id="FirstButton" onClick={this.addButtons}>FirstButton</button>
        <button id="SecondButton" onClick={this.addButtons}>SecondButton</button>
        <button id="ThirdButton" onClick={this.addButtons}>ThirdButton</button>

        <button id="FirstButton" onClick={this.removeButtons}>Remove firstButton</button>

          <ul>
            {this.state.filtersArr.map((filter, index)=>{
              return <li style={styles} key={index}>{filter.comp}</li>
            })
            }
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ButtonComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You're missing the onChangeHandler function for starters

Comment: Thanks, @Peter, but it's not related to my issue. anyways, I have added changeHandler :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the array index as your `key`, so React will reuse the first two `li` elements and drop the last one. Change `key={index}` to `key={filter.id}`, and it works as you would expect.

Update concerning the comment & downvote: I assumed uniqueness on filters in the actual code, given that the field is called `id`. The CodePen seems more of a stripped down version to show the problem. But if you do actually wish to let each button create multiple text fields, you'd indeed need to add something extra to distinguish the keys (e.g. a counter). This doesn't affect the problem as stated in the question though.

Looking at the code again, I noticed `getInput` would be an ideal candidate to extract into a separate (stateless) component, e.g. `FilterInput`. This fits better with the react model than keeping child renderings in the component state.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. it works by changing the key. Perfect catch. Thanks.

Comment: Using the `id` field of the element is not a good idea in this case if multiple of the same element can be added because the keys should be unique. It won't even let you add multiple if you click the buttons several times like it does with your initial example. See my answer for better handling of keys.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! The downvote has been removed. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code produces 3 textboxes in divs. These textboxes are updated by entering the numbers (100, 200, 300). When you click the RemoveFirstButton, the state, which stores these components, is updated and render is called.

The render function does a diff of the current state and the previous state and removes the last div, which contains the number 300. This is because, for the render function, the first element of the array changed from FirstButton to SecondButton, the second element changed from SecondButton to ThirdButton and the third element does not exist anymore.

To make it work as expected, you need to change the key of the elements from the index of the array to the id of the element, so that the render method can tell the difference between the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Changing the key works. Thanks

Comment: Using the `id` field of the element is not a good idea in this case if multiple of the same element can be added because the keys should be unique. It won't even let you add multiple if you click the buttons several times like it does with your initial example. See my answer for better handling of keys.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
Please avoid using your ids as keys as the other answers suggest if multiple of the same elements can be added as your initial example suggests because keys need to be unique and this way they can (and will) be repeated!

---

Your problem lies in the fact that you are using the key attribute wrongly.
React expects your components to have constant keys, so it can decide when and which ones it needs to update.

If you are modifying an array, the keys of the objects are changing, and the element that had the key '1' before the removal is gone afterwards and the component that previously had key '2' becomes the one with key '1' and so forth.

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) advises against using the index as key as well:
*"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the items can reorder"*

To avoid this you should use some sort of unique key generation and store each components key in it's own object, for example like this:

*In the constructor:*

```
this.nextKey = 0
```

*When adding a new component:*

```
tempArr.push({comp: comp, id: e.target.id, key: this.nextKey++});
```

*In the render function:*

```
return <li style={styles} key={filter.key}>{filter.comp}</li>
```

I modified your example to include these lines, you can find it here:
https://codepen.io/Isti115/pen/MEmMZP?editors=1111

---

Also, some other tips:

- When creating an object that has a key with a value assigned from a variable with the same name, you can shorten it so that this:
  `{comp: comp, id: e.target.id}`
  becomes this:
  `{comp, id: e.target.id}`.
- If you need something more robust, you could use a separate unique key generator like this:
  [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)
  or this:
  https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317

---

ps.: The switch statement you are using is completely useless right now. What have you tried to accomplish with it?

Comment: Agree, switch is useless.. I copied my code from project and it was just a quick post. did´t get time to clean :-)