# error: Do not use Array index in keys

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using index to generate key in a list. However, es-lint generates an error for the same. React [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) also states that using the item index as a key should be used as last resort.

```
const list = children.map((child, index) =>
    <li key={index}> {child} </li>);
```

I considered using `react-key-index`. 
`npm install react-key-index` gives following error:

`npm ERR! code E404`

`npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-key-index@latest`

Are there any suggestions on other packages that allow to generate unique key? Any suggestion on react key generator is appreciated!

Comment: What do your objects look like in `children`? Do they have an ID, or any kind of data you can hash to generate a unique ID?

Comment: If a list is never reordered (including operations like "insert" or "delete") then indices are perfectly fine. There are also other use cases, e.g. loading-on-scroll where the next page can actually contain the same item (with the same ID). In that case using index is superior to using an identifier. Actually, in most cases indices are completely fine because partial updates do not happen in every component.

Comment: In this case, list would reorder

Comment: Using a unique key (over an index value) increases performance. If you use an index and your array values shuffle around, the index is no longer unique and React cant diff the objects optimally.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

When you use index of an array as a key, React will optimize and not render as expected. What happens in such a scenario can be explained with an example.

Suppose the parent component gets an array of 10 items and renders 10 components based on the array. Suppose the 5th item is then removed from the array. On the next render the parent will receive an array of 9 items and so React will render 9 components. This will show up as the 10th component getting removed, instead of the 5th, because React has no way of differentiating between the items based on index.

Therefore always use a unique identifier as a key for components that are rendered from an array of items.

You can generate your own unique key by using any of the field of the child object that is unique as a key. Normal, any id field of the child object can be used if available.

Edit : You will only be able to see the behavior mentioned above happen if the components create and manage their own state, e.g. in uncontrolled textboxes, timers etc. E.g. [React error when removing input component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477711/react-error-when-removing-input-component)

Comment: I'm not following this example - can you provide a working example that reproduces this problem? I work with arrays constantly and have never hit this type of issue.

Comment: @lux Maybe I was not able to explain properly. Hopefully this link will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477711/react-error-when-removing-input-component

Answer (score 65):

**The issue with using `key={index}` happens whenever the list is modified.** React doesn't understand which item was added/removed/reordered since index is given on each render based on the order of the items in the array. Although, usually it's rendered fine, there are still situations when it fails.

Here is my example that I came across while building a list with input tags. One list is rendered based on index, another one based on id. The issue with the first list occurs every time you type anything in the input and then remove the item. On re-render React still shows as if that item is still there. This is a UI issue that is hard to spot and debug.

[image]

```js
    class List extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          listForIndex: [{id: 1},{id: 2}],
          listForId: [{id: 1},{id: 2}]
        }
      }
      renderListByIndex = list => {
        return list.map((item, index) => {
          const { id } = item;
          return (
              <div key={index}>
                <input defaultValue={`Item ${id}`} />
                <button 
                  style={{margin: '5px'}} 
                  onClick={() => this.setState({ listForIndex: list.filter(i => i.id !== id) })}
                 >Remove</button>
              </div>
          )
        })
      }
      renderListById = list => {
        return list.map((item) => {
          const { id } = item;
          return (
              <div key={id}>
                <input defaultValue={`Item ${id}`} />
                <button 
                  style={{margin: '5px'}} 
                  onClick={() => this.setState({ listForId: list.filter(i => i.id !== id) })}
                 >Remove</button>
              </div>
          )
        })
      }
      render() {
        const { listForIndex, listForId } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className='flex-col'>
            <div>
              <strong>key is index</strong>
              {this.renderListByIndex(listForIndex)}
            </div>
            <div>
              <strong>key is id</strong>
              {this.renderListById(listForId)}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <List />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```css
.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-col > div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root">
        <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
    </div>
```

Comment: for a second i thought my cursor was moving on its own

Comment: Here's what happens. I added two more items to the code above.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-morning-6xexu?file=/src/App.js

When you remove the first item from the top of the "key is index" list the newly created array of 3 items gonna have the keys of 0, 1, 2. Before the deletion the initial array keys were 0, 1, 2, 3.
Reacts sees the keys 0, 1, 2 (the numerical value of the keys not the array data) remained the same hence no need to rerender the items with keys 0, 1, 2. So the displayed list effectively stays the same though the array data has changed

Answer (score 11):

Of course, in React, you are required to pass in a unique key value for all elements of an array. Else, you will see this warning in console.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique “key” prop.

So, as a lazy developer, you would simply pass in the loop’s index value as the key value of the child element.

Reordering a list, or adding and removing items from a list can cause issues with the component state, when indexes are used as keys. If the key is an index, reordering an item changes it. Hence, the component state can get mixed up and may use the old key for a different component instance.

What are some exceptions where it is safe to use index as key?

- If your list is static and will not change.
- The list will never be re-ordered.
- The list will not be filtered (adding/removing item from
  the list).
- There are no ids for the items in the list.

Key should be unique but only among its siblings.

Comment: I have been received this problem but in my case, I have been putting the value of the li in the key, and that has been fixed by adding the index parameter to the map function and putting the index in the key place
`gusts.map((gust,index) => <li key={index}>{gust}</li>)`

Answer (score 3):

Do **not** use array indexes as keys, this is an anti-pattern that is pointed out by the React team in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

It's a problem for performance and for state management. The first case applies when you would append something to the top of a list. Consider an example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Element1</li>
  <li>Element2</li>
  <li>Element3</li>
</ul>
```

Now, let say you want to add new elements to the top/bottom of the list, then reorder or sort the list (or even worst - add something in the middle). All the `index`-based `key` strategy will collapse. The `index` will be different over a time, which is not the case if for each of these elements there would be a unique `id`.

CodePens:

- Using index as a key: https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/index-used-as-key
- Using ID as a key: https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/no-index-used-as-key

Play with it and you'll see that at some point the `index`-based `key` strategy is getting lost.

Comment: @Nivethan there was no codepen in this example.

Comment: are those 2 codepens links showing any code? it shows me an empty codepen page!

Answer (score 0):

*edited*

I'd suggest using the  **[uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)** librarry

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const childrenWithIds = ['one', 'two', 'three'].map((name) => ({
  id: uuidv4(),
  name
}));
//
 <div>
    {childrenWithIds.map((child) => (
      <li key={child.id}>
        {child.name}
      </li>
    ))}
  </div>
```

`uuidv4()` // will give you unique id ⇨ `'1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'`

[image]

Comment: This is the same as recreating and re-rendering each child component on every render, as it will get a different key on each render. Which also makes the child components lose their state.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Generating a new UUID for each item on every render causes exactly the problems you've outlined:

Re-rendering Issue: Since the keys change on every render, React will perceive each item as a new element in the list. This leads to unnecessary re-rendering, impacting performance.

A new approach could be to assign UUIDs to the items outside of the render method, ensuring that each item retains the same UUID across renders. Please take a look at the new example:

Answer (score -1):

In map method ,react render our array element with respect to key. so key plays a vital role. if we use index as key then in this case , if we re-order our components then , we will get problem because react  render our array element with respect to key.

For more details go through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Deu8GE3Xv50&list=PLBHcDEyoOGlQ4o_Nx6FCXmjYlOAF2am6V&index=4&t=363s

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33530792)

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using the `reactjs-id` library instead for React.js libraries, the `react-key-index` library hasn't been maintained for 7 years.

Unlike `react-uuid`, this should be able to have keys persist across page re-renders, however this hasn't been tested. I'd love to see input on this.

All you have to do on every array that requires random ids is:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactId from 'reactjs-id'

const array = ['one', 'two', 'three']

export const LineItem = item => <li key={ReactId()}>{item}</li>

export const List = () => array.map(item => <LineItem item={item} />)
```

similarly to Haddad's solution.

Comment: `reactjs-id` just generates a random GUID so has same issues as all other down voted `key={newRandomValue()}` answers.

Answer (score -6):

use the following lib "react-uuid" : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid.

react-uuid basically create random ids when you call it each time.

```
import React from 'react'
import uuid from 'react-uuid'

const array = ['one', 'two', 'three']

export const LineItem = item => <li key={uuid()}>{item}</li>

export const List = () => array.map(item => <LineItem item={item} />)
```

and this should solve the issue.

Comment: FWIW I ran into a bug with this where it is generating a new id each time an update hook runs, which in turn re-renders the same list over and over.

Comment: This will kill the performance, elements should have stable keys on re-renders.