# Unique key prop?

Tags: reactjs, key, unique

I am not sure how to solve this warning message??

"Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop".

```
  let theComments = 
  this.props.state.studentCommentReducer.studentCommentReducer.map((comments) => {
  return <CommentsItem key={comments.id} comments={comments} />;
  });



     Student: {this.props.comments.comment}
```

Comment: Is it as simple as changing comments.id to something else?

Answer (score 2):

In some way you need to specify a key for each item. You can do something like this

```
...map((comments) => {
  return <CommentsItem key={comments.id} comments={comments} />;
});
```

or

```
...map((comments, i) => {
  return <CommentsItem key={i} comments={comments} />;
});
```

Ref.: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an unique key for each of the mapped `CommentsItem`, [preferably not the index of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735689/2345964).

In your code, make sure that `comments.id` is unique. That would solve the warning message you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index as the key only to the lists which are static .try using others as key