# React JS state updates for collections of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render

I'm pretty new to React, and I'm trying to practice by building a simple notes app. As far as I can tell it's going great, but! I read that state should not be updated manually, so I'm copying my state array and filtering out a result for a removal operation.

But it fails! Rather, if I console log, it *correctly removes the to-be-deleted element from the state array*, however, when I call setState() on the copy to update my view, the list is wrong!

For some reason my React list is always removing the last element visually from the page, and appears then out of sync with my state.

The app itself is a Form container of sorts with a nested list and list-item component, which use props from the form class to manage.

What am I doing wrong?

**Form Class**

```
class NotesForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const list = [
     { text: "Build out UI" },
     { text: "Add new note" },
     { text: "delete notes" },
     { text: "edit notes" }
   ];

    this.state = {
      'notes': list
    };

    // this.notes = list;
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.deleteNote = this.deleteNote.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.input.value.length === 0) { return; }

    this.state.notes.push({text: this.input.value});
    this.setState({ notes: this.state.notes });

    this.input.value = "";
  }

  // BUG - deletes WRONG note!!
  deleteNote(note) {
    console.log({'DELETE_NOTE': note.text})
    // var list = _.clone(this.state.notes);
    var list = [...this.state.notes];

    var filteredNotes = _.filter(list, function(n) {
      return (n.text !== note.text);
    })

    console.log({
      'list': list,
      'filteredNotes': filteredNotes
    })

    this.setState({ notes: filteredNotes });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row notes-form">
        <div className="col-xs-12">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" className="new-note-input" ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
            <br />
            <button className="add-btn btn btn-info btn-block" type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add</button>
            <br />
            <NotesList notes={this.state.notes} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**List Class**

```
class NotesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="notes-list">
        {this.props.notes.map((n, index) => <NotesListItem key={index} note={n} deleteNote={this.props.deleteNote} />)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

**List Item Class**

```
class NotesListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      'text': props.note.text
    };

    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
  }

  delete() {
    this.props.deleteNote(this.props.note);
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <li className="notes-list-item">
        <span className="item-text">{this.state.text}</span>
        <div className="notes-btn-group btn-group" role="group">
          <button className="delete-btn btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={this.delete}>&times;</button>
        </div>
      </li>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The variable "list" is not defined in NotesForm, please add your App component to your post. Or better : create a demo of your bug with https://codesandbox.io and share the link.

Comment: Oops! I've edited and added the constant I was using for "list". I'll also look at setting this up on codesandbox, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like a unique id instead of `index` as the `key` for each `NotesListItem` in `NotesList`. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys) (maybe a duplicate actually):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NotesListItem from './NotesListItem';

class NotesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="notes-list">
        {this.props.notes.map((n, index) => <NotesListItem key={n.id} note={n} deleteNote={this.props.deleteNote} />)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default NotesList;
```

You can use something like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate a "unique" id. There are many ways you could generate a unique key, but it depends on your data structure. Also using a unique id and filtering based on the id, can help avoid a situation where two notes in the array have the same text as filtering based on the `text` value would delete both of them.

```
import uuidv1 from 'uuid/v1';

// ...

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.input.value.length === 0) { return; }

  this.state.notes.push({id: uuidv1(), text: this.input.value});
  this.setState({ notes: this.state.notes });

  this.input.value = "";
}
```

I only suggest to use something like this as it's possible your text could be duplicated. You could probably even get away with using something like:

```
{this.props.notes.map((n, index) => <NotesListItem key={index + n.text} note={n} deleteNote={this.props.deleteNote} />)}
```

Also, you shouldn't be directly mutating state like `this.state.notes.push({text: this.input.value});`. Try something like this instead:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.input.value.length === 0) { return; }

  const note = { id: uuidv1(), text: this.input.value };
  const notes = [...this.state.notes, note];

  this.setState({ notes });

  this.input.value = "";
}
```

Also, I'd avoid using `ref` for handling controlled inputs, especially to set value. Why not create a property on state that handles the value of the input in combination with a simple `onChange` event handler. This would be in line with the React [Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) documentation and the "standard" React way of handling input value updates:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.text.length === 0) { return; }

  const note = { id: uuidv1(), text: this.state.text };
  const notes = [...this.state.notes, note];

  this.setState({ text: '', notes });
}

render() {
  // ...
  <input type="text" className="new-note-input" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  // ...
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dbxhe2) in action.

The other answer may be enough to resolve your issue. I'd recommend to review the following [article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) mentioned/linked in the React [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) documentation discuss the potential negative impacts of using an index as a key.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: For this small example, it's fine to use the index as the key.

Comment: @jkerr838 I added a note regarding the benefits of using a unique id when doing filter. To help avoid deleting other notes with the same potential/duplicate text.

Comment: Perfect! it was definitely the key that was the issue. I tried (new Date()).getMilliseconds() but it was so fast I still got duplicate keys. I tried the uuid package and the notes deleting works exactly as expectd. Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I'd very, very much recommend to also implement the suggestion by @jkerr838 of using `this.props.note.text` instead of copying the value of `text` to state in `NotesListItem`. It's an important distinction and his explanation regarding that was fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a Component only runs once. React will reuse component instances passing them new props. The problem here is that NodeListItem caches the text of the note in its own local state and uses that text in the render method. When its Parent passes a new note to it via the props, it does not use it. It uses the state which is now stale.

Child components should usually use data from props passed in by the Parent.

```
class NotesListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // The problem is this statement here
    this.state = {
      'text': props.note.text
    };

    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Here is a fixed version of the `NotesListItem` class.

```
class NotesListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
  }

  delete() {
    this.props.deleteNote(this.props.note);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="notes-list-item">
        <span className="item-text">{this.props.note.text}</span> {/* <-- using props */}
        <div className="notes-btn-group btn-group" role="group">
          <button
            className="delete-btn btn btn-danger"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.delete}
          >
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```