# React index key is not working in the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have used `index` key but it's still showing errors. Also tried with unique id from JSON data but can't solve this.

**ERROR**

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
const faqdata = this.props.faqData.map((faq, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
            {faq.description}
    </li>
));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js) and [error: Do not use Array index in keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Warning:** Each child in a list should have a unique "**key**" prop.

You will get this warning only when two or more items in the list have been supplied with the same **key**, Your code looks fine for me, it shouldn't be giving this `warning`, please try with a console.log(index) inside the `map`.

```
const faqdata = this.props.faqData.map((faq, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    <li key={index}>
            {faq.description}
    </li>
});
```

> **Anti Pattern:**

You should not be using **index** of the map for you **Key**, its an antipattern,
it may lead to unpredictable results.

Please check this https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

You should be using proper **unique-id** for your **Key**, like a **DB id** or some unique-id.

This Key is used internally to identify the DOM elements to render and not to render again.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ID, non duplicate name (or whatever unique you call it) but its index, because it compares the VDOM by its key:value pairs

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect to other answers quoting that you should not use array index as a key, as much as it is an antipattern, it will still resolve the warning.

What you're doing is right and should remove the warning. Although I suspect the warning is coming when you iterate again over the result of your `faqdata`.

Every time you render something from an array, each entry should have the key attribute.