# how to push an deleted list from an array to an empty array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two sections side by side in a page, left section has an array list, what i want to do is, on click of li i want to delete it form left, and want to display on the right side. Iam not getting how to push it to right and delete from left.

```
displayLeftSide = () => {
  let  list = this.state.leftItems.map((lists, i) => {
    return <li onClick={()=> this.deleteLeftItem(lists.key)} key={i}>
      {lists}</li> ;
  });
  return list;
}

deleteLeftItem(index) {
  let arr = [...this.state.leftItems];
  let array = [...this.state.rightItems];
  array.push(index, 1);
  arr.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({rightItems: array});
  this.setState({leftItems: arr});
  console.log(arr)
  console.log(array)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method with wrong args and as a result you actually don't add item to the right side. 
Please try this code:

```
deleteLeftItem(index) {
  const item = this.state.leftItems[index]

  const leftItemsCopy = [...this.state.leftItems]
  const rightItemsCopy = [...this.state.rightItems]
  leftItemsCopy.splice(index, 1) // rmeoves item from left side
  rightItemsCopy.push(item)

  this.setState({
    leftItems: leftItemsCopy,
    rightItems: rightItemsCopy
  })

}
```

Besides, when calling `deleteLeftItem` method you should pass item index as argument:

```
return <li onClick={()=> this.deleteLeftItem(i)} key={i}>
```

There is also another issue. Generally it's a bad idea to use array indices as keys (anti-pattern). Each item should have some unique prop (e.g. `id`) and it should be used as key. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys).

You can check official redux [doc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) for more immutable update patterns

Comment: `.splice` returns removed elements from array, you need `.slice`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly You're right. Sorry, updated. I've confused `splice` with `slice`... my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Error is updating removed array with deleted entries from left array. This is the working solution of this problem,

```js
const {useState} = React;
function App() {
  const [arr, updateArr] = useState([
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five"
  ]);
  const [removedArray, updateRemovedArray] = useState([]);
  function removeHandler(datum) {
    let arrClone = arr;
    var index = arrClone.indexOf(datum);

    if (index > -1) {
      arrClone.splice(index, 1);
    }
    updateArr([...arrClone]);
    let removedArrayClone = removedArray;
    removedArrayClone.push(datum);
    updateRemovedArray([...removedArrayClone]);
  }
  function addHandler(datum) {
    let removedArrayClone = removedArray;
    var index = removedArrayClone.indexOf(datum);

    if (index > -1) {
      removedArrayClone.splice(index, 1);
    }
    updateRemovedArray([...removedArrayClone]);
    let arrClone = arr;
    arrClone.push(datum);
    updateArr([...arrClone]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="left-section">
        <center>
          <h3>Original Array</h3>
          {arr.length > 0 ? (
            <ul>
              {arr.map((datum, index) => (
                <li
                  className="tooltip"
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => removeHandler(datum)}
                >
                  <b>{datum}</b>
                  <span className=" bgColorRemove tooltiptext">
                    Delete this item
                  </span>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <h5>No data</h5>
          )}
        </center>
      </div>
      <div className="right-section">
        <center>
          <h3>Removed Entries</h3>
          {removedArray.length > 0 ? (
            <ul>
              {removedArray.map((datum, index) => (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  className="tooltip"
                  onClick={() => addHandler(datum)}
                >
                  <b>{datum}</b>
                  <span className="bgColorAdd tooltiptext">Add this item</span>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <h5>No data</h5>
          )}
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left-section {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
.right-section {
}
.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bgColorAdd {
  background-color: green;
}
.bgColorRemove {
  background-color: red;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```