# Can I use index of map function as key for my React components containing dynamic unpredictable text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I got this code where I'm parsing dynamic text into separate lines and rendering individual components for each line of text.

I'm using the `map` function to create an array for the elements and **React demands a unique key for each element on the list**.

I know usually it's not ideal to use `index` as the key. But in this case, what else can I do?

**QUESTION**

Can I use `index` as the `key` for the elements in this case without having issues? What could go wrong?

**Note1**: I cannot use the values as the keys, because all lines might have the exact same values, hence they wouldn't be unique.

**Note2**: This code runs inside an Admin form for BlogPosts. I write some custom markup text, just like in the textarea for questions on StackOverflow and I need to parse it to give it proper styles when rendered out on the screen as a blog post. Like: `**bold text**`, etc. And each line should be rendered as a different paragraph.

**UPDATE:**

I've read the article you all mentioned in comments and answer. And here's what the author points out:

---

[image]

Does my case meet all 3 requirements?

1 - Do they change? In theory they do.

2 - They have no ids.

3 - They are not filtered for sure. But are they reordered? What if you copy `"line1\nline2\nline3"` paste into Notepad and change it to `"line3\nline2\nline1"` and paste it back into the `textarea`. Does it count as re-ordering? I just tested it and it renders just fine.

Anyway, so far I haven't run into any issues and it feels safe to use. But I would like an in-depth explanation of how it works in this case.

---

```js
function App() {
  const [inputValue,setInputValue] = React.useState("line1\nline2\nline3");
  const lineItems = inputValue.split("\n").map((line,index) => 
    <TextLine 
      key={index}
      index={index}
      value={line}
    />
  );
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <textarea 
        onChange={()=>setInputValue(event.target.value)} 
        value={inputValue}
        style={{width: "300px", height: "60px"}}
      />
      {lineItems}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function TextLine(props) {
  return(
    <div>{props.value + " (key = " + props.index + ")"}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I think that using index is not considered wrong but to be extra sure you can use UUID. This is just a precaution, not a deaddrop requirement.

Comment: here you can find a good article on when it's not a very good idea to use index as key.
https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: as long as you don't rearrange or filter the array, it's safe.

Comment: Yes, U can. Someone can say that u can't do that, it's kinda antipattern, but u can and in my opinion, it's no so bad. Even u can generate keys like key={"text-line${index}"}, if u want to make them unique

Comment: here is the answer that explains how should you use it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735689/6818430

Comment: @NavinGelot that not exactly my case. Try to select the full `line1` from my snippet and delete. You'll see that it renders just fine. React won't think you've deleted the last line, like the answer you're mentioning. Somehow it's a different situation from mine, but I can't put it in words the difference.

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: Don't use the index if the items have a unique id (and a non-primitives list should), because it's an [anti-pattern as per documentation](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

When you don't have a unique id for the items, you can use the index.

```
const Numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

const App = () => (
  <ul>
  {Numbers.map (
    (number, index) => <li key={index}>{number}</li>
  )}
  </ul>
)
```

Without a unique key, React couldn’t differentiate if the element was removed or just the content is changed.

Solutions for unique key...

1- You can create a function to generate unique keys/ids/numbers/strings and use that

2- You can use npm packages(library) like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid), [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid)...

3- I recommend using the unique ID you get from the database, If you get it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added some more details to my question about the article you've mentioned.

Comment: can I use a prefix+index?

Comment: @Snowmanzzz yes, you can.

Comment: my mentor told me not to do so, he force me to use (eg. Students) student.id, but I say we may not have id some times

Comment: @Snowmanzzz that's correct but when you don't have any id in your array of objects, then you can try prefix + index. I would recommend to ask your backend devs to provide unique id in your array of objects.

Comment: @akhtarvahid so you mean there're shortage for using "prefix + index"?