# React remove object from list of objects without unique value, using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to remove object from my list by clicking on delete icon, but with my logic either everything is deleted from list or nothing, I am not sure how to do it without provided ID to object, I don't have anything unique and I am kinda lost.
Component that renders as many Food as there is in useState:

```
 {cartFood.map((food) => {
    return (
      <CartFood
         key={Math.random()}
         foodName={food.foodName}
         foodPrice={food.foodPrice}
         numberOfPortions={food.numberOfPortions}
         cartFood={cartFood}
         setCartFood={setCartFood}
      />
    );
 })}
```

Logic for removing that particular item that is selected (which is not working and also bad solution since there can be case where you get same name and price twice)

```
const CartFood = ({
  foodName,
  foodPrice,
  numberOfPortions,
  cartFood,
  setCartFood,
}) => {
  const handleRemoveFood = () => {
    setCartFood(
      cartFood.filter(
        (el) =>
          el.foodName &&
          el.foodPrice !== cartFood.foodName &&
          cartFood.foodPrice
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='cartFood-container'>
      <p>{foodName}</p>
      <p>x{numberOfPortions}</p>
      <p>{foodPrice}kn</p>
      <p>
        <MdDeleteForever
          className='cartFood__icon'
          onClick={handleRemoveFood}
        />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartFood;
```

List of objects looks like this:

```
[{
  foodName: "Njoki with sos"
  foodPrice: 35
  numberOfPortions: 1
}, 
{
  foodName: "Chicken Wingos"
  foodPrice: 45
  numberOfPortions: 2
}]
```

Comment: You think of this `const [cartFood, setCartFood] = useState([]);` or something else?

Comment: As long as your list items aren't overly large and your list is very long, you can also just compare the list items as string: cartFood.filter((el) => JSON.stringify(el) !== JSON.stringify(cartFood))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in [your repo](https://github.com/matej24/food-shop):

1. Just pass the `food._id` to `FoodCard` so you access it when you want to add or remove an item from cart:

*FoodList.js*

```
const foodList = (typeOfList) =>
  typeOfList.map(food => {
    return (
      <FoodCard
        key={food._id}
        foodId={food._id}
        foodName={food.title}
        foodPrice={food.price}
        foodPic={food.image}
        setCartFood={setCartFood}
        cartFood={cartFood}
      />
    );
  });
```

*FoodCard.js*

```
const handleAddToCard = () => {
    setCartFood([
      ...cartFood,
      {
        foodId,
        foodName,
        foodPrice,
        numberOfPortions,
      },
    ]);
  };
```

*CartFood.js*

```
const handleRemoveFood = () => {
    setCartFood(cartFood => cartFood.filter((el) => el.foodId !== foodId));
  };
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit crazy-browser-fhw9m]

2. You could use `useReducer` with `useContext` so you don't have to pass props down manually at every level, check [this article](https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/) for more info
3. You don't need to pass the `cartFood` as a property just for updating the state since you can use [`setState` callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
setCartFood(cartFood => [
      ...cartFood,
      {
        foodId,
        foodName,
        foodPrice,
        numberOfPortions,
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: Hm...I opened your example on codesandbox but when I wanna delete item from cart nothing happens :/
p.s. Thanks for article definetly gonna read it

Answer (score 3):

- Put the index of the item in the array as the `id`. Pass it as your id.

```
 {cartFood.map((food, index) => {
              return (
                <CartFood
                  key={index}
                  id={index}
                  foodName={food.foodName}
                  foodPrice={food.foodPrice}
                  numberOfPortions={food.numberOfPortions}
                  cartFood={cartFood}
                  setCartFood={setCartFood}
                />
              );
            })}
```

- Use the id to remove the food.

```
const CartFood = ({
  foodName,
  foodPrice,
  numberOfPortions,
  cartFood,
  setCartFood,
  id,
}) => {
  const handleRemoveFood = () => {
    setCartFood(cartFood.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className='cartFood-container'>
      <p>{foodName}</p>
      <p>x{numberOfPortions}</p>
      <p>{foodPrice}kn</p>
      <p>
        <MdDeleteForever
          className='cartFood__icon'
          onClick={handleRemoveFood}
        />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hm... I think I messed up something since ur soultion should work but everything from cart is removed, not just that specific item...

Comment: Yes, I tried to suggest edit but I couldint since it is only one charachter, problem continues, everything is removed from cart, and not only specific item, is it possible I messed something else? Do I need to spread something, maybe?

Comment: Do check again, the code should work. I've updated. You need to check the id which comes as the prop in your filter function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222604/discussion-between-matej-and-prateek-thapa).

Comment: @PrateekThapa It is not recommended to use indexes for keys if the order of items may change: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @Fraction Understandable but since the owner of the code is a newbie and the item of an array really doesn't have a unique identity here. I admit this is an anti-pattern. But that shouldn't be a problem for this solution now. I don't think we should deep dive a newbie in what's right and wrong. Fixing an issue is a huge help I do admire you concern though.

Comment: It's really a problem, especially in the case of deletion, which is what the OP is trying to do

Comment: @Fraction I don't think so. The OP is updating the array in itself which causes the whole of array to change triggering a re-render. The architecture the OP has made with the component will have no effect on `index` as a key since, on every item update, the array itself changes.

Comment: look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781201/11129751, maybe you understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work :

```js
const handleRemoveFood = (obj) => {
        setCartFood((oldList) => oldList.filter((item) => item.foodName !== obj.foodName));
    };
```

Your button (icon) should call this function with current object data (obj)

A working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-isz6c?file=/index.js

Comment: I updated my code with @Prateek's solution, can I use id on function you showed here?

Comment: I tried, still same, nothing happens, that specific items still stay in cart, I dont know whats wrong...