# array of objects from a different component in react not mapping in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping an array of objects I imported from a different component but I get the error

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

with the following error details

> Check the top-level render call using . See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
> at li
> at Heading2
> at div
> at div
> at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.jsx:27:17)
> at Layout (webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.jsx:16:19)
> at $29383e587d62412a$export$9f8ac96af4b1b2ae (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/main.js:42:28)
> at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:28:18)
> at StyleRegistry (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/index/index.js:671:34)
> at AppContainer (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:404:29)
> at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:433:57)
> at div
> at Body (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:690:21)

Following is the component containing the array
Menu.jsx

```
export const mainDetails = [
    {
        heading: 'CUSTOM SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT',
        list: ['- Solutions tailored to specitic business needs', '- Domain experience', '- Technical excellence', '- Process visibility', '- Constraint management framework', '- Non-functional requirements match']
      },
      {
        heading: 'DEVELOPMENT TEAM AUGMENTATION',
        list: ['- Solutions tailored to specitic business needs', '- Domain experience', '- Technical excellence', '- Process visibility', '- Constraint management framework', '- Non-functional requirements match']
      },
      {
        heading: 'IT CONSULTING AND DIGITAL ADVISORY',
        list: ['- Solutions tailored to specitic business needs', '- Domain experience', '- Technical excellence', '- Process visibility', '- Constraint management framework', '- Non-functional requirements match']
      },
      {
        heading: 'SOFTWARE RE-ENGINEERING AND SUPPORT',
        list: ['- Solutions tailored to specitic business needs', '- Domain experience', '- Technical excellence', '- Process visibility', '- Constraint management framework', '- Non-functional requirements match']
      }
]
```

Following is the component containing the mapping of the array
Heading.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import {mainDetails} from './Menus'

const Heading2 = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      {mainDetails.map(detail => (
        <div className="card">  
          <div className='done'>
            <div>
              <h5 className='font-normal pl-8 text-[#E54416] pb-4 text-lg'>{detail.heading}</h5>
              <ul>{detail.list.map(listItems=>(
                <li>{listItems}</li>
              ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      ))}
      
      
    </main>
  )
}

export default Heading2
```

Also, when I add the key prop to the list like this `<ul>{detail.list.map(listItems, i =>(<li key={i}>{listItems}</li>))}`, I get a new error saying ***listItems is undefined***

Comment: `./Menus` won't import `Menu.jsx` - Also give `<div className="card">` a unique key prop. Read more about it https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: When you return JSX from the .map callback, the root element must have the key. Fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jones-o12njm?file=/src/Heading2.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **never** use an array index to provide a key to your list:

> The issue with using key={index} happens whenever the list is modified. React doesn't understand which item was added/removed/reordered since index is given on each render based on the order of the items in the array. Although, usually it's rendered fine, there are still situations when it fails.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys) for more explanation.

That said, you need a unique key for the the first map `mainDetails.map()` and the `heading` seems to be a good choice. You also need an unique key for the `detail.list.map()`, you can create one by merging the `heading` and the `listItems` value together like `detail.heading + listItems`:

```html
    <main>
      {mainDetails.map(detail => (
        <div key={detail.heading} className="card">  
          <div className='done'>
            <div>
              <h5 className='font-normal pl-8 text-[#E54416] pb-4 text-lg'>{detail.heading}</h5>
              <ul>{detail.list.map(listItems=>(
                <li key={detail.heading + listItems}>{listItems}</li>
              ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      ))}      
    </main>
```