# How to pull specific data from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have created an array that gives a certain ID to each component every time it is added to the array. But now that the component is created, I want to be able to pull the data. Like the **boxid** or **title** when needed.

I currently am trying to make the value of `<textarea />` in **Todobox.jsx** the unique **boxid**. But it does not seem to print a value.

**Here is my code:**

**ElementContext.js:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Todobox from './components/Todobox';

export const ElementContext = createContext();

export const ElementContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
    const [elementId, setElementId] = useState(0);
    const [refDict, setRefDict] = useState({});

    const newElementId = (elements) =>{
        setElementId(elementId + 1);
        console.log(elementId)
    }

    const newElement = () => {
        newElementId();
        if (!refDict[elementId]) { //so if nothing in "refDict" that means the elementId is unique
          setElements(prev => [...prev, { title: 'Placeholder', boxid: elementId }]);
          setRefDict((prev) => ({...prev, [elementId]: true}));
        }
        console.log(elements);
      };

    const value = {
        elements,
        setElements,
        newElement,
        elementId
    };

    return(
        <ElementContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ElementContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

**HomePage.jsx:**

```
import react from 'react';
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Todobox from './Todobox';
import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';

export default function HomePage(){
    const { elements, setElements, newElement, elementId } = useContext(ElementContext);

    return(
        <div className='page-container'>
        <div className='header'>
          <a className='header-title'>Trello Clone!</a>
          <a className='header-button' onClick={newElement}>Create a list</a>
        </div>
      <div className='element-field'>
        
         {elements.map((elements, elementId) => <Todobox key={elementId} />)}
        
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**Todobox.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { ElementContext } from '../ElementContext';

export default function Todobox(){
    const { elements, setElements, newElement, elementId } = useContext(ElementContext);
    return(
        <div className='element-box'>
            <a className='element-title'>PlaceHolder</a>
            <Item />
            <textarea 
            className='element-input' 
            type='text' 
            placeholder={elements.boxid}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am pretty new to react and such so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .
please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `elements` array in state (and context) is an array of objects, and those objects have a `boxid` property. To use it, you need to reference or pass down that property when iterating over the elements. So your starting point would be to change this line:

```
elements.map((elements, elementId) => <Todobox key={elementId} />)
```

I'd change `Todobox` so that it doesn't use context at all, and is instead passed down all values it needs to render from the parent, including the `boxid`.

Other issues:

- The `.map` callback parameter is not an array - it's a single object, so it should probably be called `element`, not `elements`, to avoid confusion
- Keys [should usually not be the index of the element in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys). Use a more unique identifier, such as the `boxid`, which will never change for a particular object. (In your current implementation, the `elementId` in the `.map` callback may not reflect the actual `boxid` of the object being iterated over, if you ever remove an item from the middle of the state array.)

```
elements.map((element) => <Todobox key={element.boxid} boxid={element.boxid} />)
```

```
export default function Todobox({ boxid }){
    return(
        <div className='element-box'>
            <a className='element-title'>PlaceHolder</a>
            <Item />
            <textarea 
            className='element-input' 
            type='text' 
            placeholder={boxid}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```