# Modal in react not showing when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

When I click the p tag the modal box shows up, but the title and text of the selected item in sidebarTitle, is not showing. I Have made an array with different titles and text, and I would like them to show up inside the modal, when a press one of their titles. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../sidebarStyles.css";

function Modal({ title, text, closeModal }) {
  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <span className="close" onClick={closeModal}>
          X
        </span>
        <div className="content">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const sidebarTitle = [
  {
    title: "Text",
    text: "Modal",
  },
  {
    title: "Scope",
    text: "Modal",
  },
  {
    title: "Analysis",
    text: "Modal",
  },
];

function Sidebar() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(false);

  const handleTitleClick = () => {
    setSelectedItem(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setSelectedItem(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      {sidebarTitle.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p onClick={handleTitleClick}>{item.title}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      {selectedItem ? (
        <Modal
          title={selectedItem.title}
          text={selectedItem.text}
          closeModal={closeModal}
          className="modal"
        />
      ) : (
        !selectedItem
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: You just need to set the clicked title object in the selectedItem state. Send the item to the handleTitleClick function, and set it to the state ==> **setSelectedItem(item)** The default state should be **null** instead of **false**. Also, in closeModal function set default state ==> **setSelectedItem(null)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `selectedItem` is a boolean state variable, and so it won't have any properties such as `title` or `text`, that's why you aren't able to view anything on the UI. You can instead change it to an object such as -

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({ visible: false, title: null, text: null})
```

and then, change your functions in this way -

```
const handleTitleClick = (title, text) => {
  setSelectedItem({
    visible: true,
    title: title,
    text: text
  }); 
};
```

and -

```
const closeModal = () => {
  setSelectedItem({
    visible: false,
    title: null,
    text: null
  });
};
```

and change your p tag to look like this -
`<p onClick={()=>handleTitleClick(item.title, item.text)}>{item.title}</p>`

and to display the modal, instead of using `selectedItem`, use `selectedItem.visible` instead.
if any other explanation is required, do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectedItem` is of type `boolean`, so `selectedItem.title` get's you undefined.
Change your handler to :

```
const handleTitleClick = (item) => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
  };
```

and your map function to :

```
      {sidebarTitle.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p onClick={() => handleTitleClick(item)}>{item.title}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
```

And try not to use index as a key value. More on that topic here => [error: Do not use Array index in keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys)