# React DOM shows first element instead of filtered elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a page on my website where I am mapping through an array of projects (similar to something like monday.com) and I am now building the filter functionality that allows a user to search for a project by title, but I've encountered the most bizarre behavior. Through a lot of console logging, I have determined that the search term is successfully matched to specific projects and the state is being updated correctly, however, the DOM only displays the first element of the original state array. (ex. if I have the array: ['website redesign', 'marketing strategy', 'payroll update'] and I search 'payroll update', the state array is updated to just the term 'payroll update' but the DOM will show 'website redesign'.)

Here are the relevant state variables:

```
const [unfilteredProjects, setUnfilteredProjects] = useState<Project[]>([])
const [projects, setProjects] = useState<Project[]>([])
const [subitems, setSubitems] = useState<Subitem[]>([]);
const [titleFilter, setTitleFilter] = useState('');
```

Here is the filter functionality:

```
useEffect(() => {    
    var newArray = unfilteredProjects.filter(proj => {
      return proj.title.toUpperCase().includes(titleFilter.toUpperCase());
    })
    console.log(newArray)

    setProjects([...newArray])
}, [titleFilter])
```

Here is how I update the filter:

```
<input onChange={(e) => setTitleFilter(e.currentTarget.value)} type="text" placeholder='Search' className={cx(styles.searchInput, theme.darkMode && styles.darkMode)}/>
```

Here is where I'm mapping through the array:

```
{
  projects.map((project: Project, index) => {      
    console.log(project.title)              
    return (              
      <div key={index}>
        <div>
          <h1>{project.title}</h1>               
        </div>                               
      </div> 
    )
  })
}
```

This is not the first time I've had to build filters in React; I've pored over code where I've done pretty much the exact same thing, but could not find a difference. In addition to a useEffect being triggered when the filter is changed, I have tried calling a function ever time the user types, and updating the state from there, to no avail. I have simplified a lot of the code, so if more is needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could it be that the key you are using is the index? so after you search, the index is the same. Try to use the project title as the key for example. Just a guess

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: @CaioOliveira It was the key! I changed it to the project title and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: duplicate: [error: Do not use Array index in keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735483/error-do-not-use-array-index-in-keys)