# Generating sequential IDs for ReactJS keys

Tags: reactjs

React requires that you have a unique `key` attribute on elements in an array.  The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) recommend using an `id` from your data.  If you don't have an `id` then you can use the array index as a "last resort", with the caveat that using an index can cause performance issues when the items can be re-ordered.  I've also had some annoying issues when building an array of elements from multiple source arrays and multiple calls to `.map()`, each with different transformations, in which case the array indexes won't be unique anyways.

I've started throwing the following boilerplate into my components:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getId = this.getId.bind(this);
    this.id = 0;
}

getId() {
    return this.id++;
}
```

which can be used like so:

```
render() {
    const items = this.props.greetings.map(text => ({
        <li key={this.getId()}>{text}</li>
    }));

    return (
        <ul>
          {items}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

This is simple, fast, and doesn't have the issues that using the array index has, but I don't know if there are any issue with this approach or better alternatives that I'm overlooking.  Is this bad practice?  Are there any other simple ways of generating `key`s that don't have the array index issues?

Comment: `key` prop doesn't need to be an integer. You can pass any string to key. So if your `text` prop is unique among the other sibling components you can just pass that as `key` prop.

Comment: @bennygenel this was a contrived example. You can assume that `text` is not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the docs on [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) have to say on keys

> In practice, finding a key is usually not hard. The element you are going to display may already have a unique ID, so the key can just come from your data.
>   When that’s not the case, **you can add a new ID property to your model** or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.
>   As a last resort, you can pass item’s index in the array as a key. This can work well if the items are never reordered, but reorders will be slow.

So I think you are following the suggested approach.

Comment: It seems like my approach wouldn't have the issues with slow reordering, right? Wonder why the docs don't recommend something like this... I guess the one drawback is all the boilerplate, when you don't care much about performance that's hard to justify...

Comment: No, you are safe from slow reordering as you create ids explicitly. The docs do say that you should use the array indices as keys as a last resort. Check out one of the questions I came across which shows what might happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477711/react-error-when-removing-input-component

Comment: Also, to get around the boilerplate, you can create a HOC which would add an id prop to any component which you might want to use in an array. Just  a thought.